# Clicking button game logic not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

In my script whenever you click a "Button" it adds 1 to your score. When you miss the button 10 times total it loads a new scene and you lose the game. When you click the button it resets the total back to 0. The problem im having is that if you miss the button 9 times and then click it on the 10th time it still counts to 10 and it loads the new screen and you lose.

What it should be doing is resetting it back to 0 and you can continue to play.

**loseObject sets the amount to 0 when the game begins and when the button is pressed.**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]

public class ButtonReposition : MonoBehaviour
{
public Button prefab;
public GameObject loseObject;
private int count;
public Text countText;

// Use this for initialization

void Start()
{
    count = 0;
    SetCountText();
    float x = Random.Range(325f, -600f);
    float y = Random.Range(250f, -450f);
    Debug.Log(x + "," + y);
    prefab.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(x, y);
    loseObject.GetComponent<Lose>().amount = 0;
}

public void Move()
{
    float x = Random.Range(325f, -600f);
    float y = Random.Range(250f, -450f);
    Debug.Log(prefab.transform.position.x + "," + prefab.transform.position.y);
    prefab.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(x, y);
    loseObject.GetComponent<Lose>().amount = 0;
    count = count + 1;
    SetCountText();
}

void SetCountText()
{
    countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString();
}
}
```

**And on get mouse button down it adds 1 to the total and loads the next scene.**

```
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Lose : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject Button;
public GameObject Target;
public GameObject loseObject;
public int amount;
public ButtonReposition script;
public void ChangeScene(int changeTheScene)   

{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(changeTheScene);
}

void Start()
{

}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        amount += 1;
        Debug.Log(amount);
        if (amount == 10)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
            Destroy(Button);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: *"In my script whenever you click a "Button" it adds 1 to your score"* You mean clicking on an UI button or simply clicking the left mouse button? *"When you miss the button 10 times total it loads a new scene"* What do you mean by when you miss? Miss what? How do you determine the miss?

Comment: By the way, you need to fix the code in your question. Your `SceneManager.LoadScene` is missing a function....

Comment: Yes, clicking on a UI button adds 1 to the score. If you don't click on the button a total of 10 times in a row it loads the new scene and you lose. The miss is determined using on click, so if you click and the UI button is not pressed it adds 1.

Comment: That makes sense. I see so many problems already. What are you using as a Button? Sprite Renderer or UI (Image) component? How many Buttons do you have  that will be clicked on? Your script needs to be heavily modified. Please edit it and add the names of the script and include the declared variable names so that I can take a look at it.

Comment: For the button i am using an image component with the unity button code. There is 1 button that is clicked on. Code has been updated above.

Comment: Final question "When you click the button it resets the total back to 0"...Can you explain that?

Comment: When the button is clicked it sets amount to 0. Sorry for all the confusion!

Comment: Ok. And the score remains the-same? Or does it reset too?

Comment: Yes the score remains the same until the game is over. Then it resets back to 0.

Comment: Not sure but check my answer and get back to me. If you don't click the button 10 times, it will load new scene. If you don't click the button 9 times then click the button, it will reset it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other to get this right, you have to find a way to determine when the moue button is down and Button is clicked. You are not doing that now. What you are doing now is checking when left mouse Button is clicked with `if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))`.

This is one of the cases, where using the `Image` component is better than using the `Button` component. Unless you really need the Button component here, the `Image` component should be used.

This can be done with `IPointerDownHandler`, `IPointerUpHandler` interface with their `OnPointerDown` and `OnPointerUp` functions.

Disable your `ButtonReposition` script for now. Use the script below and see if that's doing what you expected. If everything is fine you can then enable your `ButtonReposition` script and remove the unnecessary stuff inside it.

Attach the ButtonDetector to your Image Component:

```
public class ButtonDetector : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public bool clicked = false;

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        clicked = true;
        //Debug.Log("Pointer Down!");
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //Reset
        clicked = false;
        // Debug.Log("Pointer Up!");
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }
}
```

Your new Lose script:

```
public class Lose : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Button;
    public GameObject Target;
    public GameObject loseObject;


    public int missedAmount = 0;
    public int clickedAmount = 0;
    const int MISSED_MAX_AMOUNT = 10;

    //public ButtonReposition script;
    public void ChangeScene(int changeTheScene)

    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(changeTheScene);
    }

    private ButtonDetector buttonImage;

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("ButtonImage");
        buttonImage = obj.GetComponent<ButtonDetector>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (buttonImage.clicked)
            {

                Debug.Log("Mouse Clicked on Button!");
                clickedAmount++;
                //Reset missedAmount to 0
                missedAmount = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Mouse Click on SOMETHING ELSE");
                missedAmount++;
            }

            if (missedAmount == 10)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("GameOver!");
                Debug.LogWarning("Missed 10 times in a row!");
                SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
                //Destroy(buttonImage.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i appreciate this more than you could imagine. Im not home at the moment but when i get home ill definitely try it out and see how it goes.

Comment: Ok. See you then and happy coding.

Comment: Hi again, I have fixed a couple of problems but now im stuck with one error. **Where it has "if buttonImage.clicked)" comes up with this.** NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Solution 'Blinded' ‎(1 project) Assets/Scripts/Lose.cs 37

Comment: You have to make sure that your Button/Image is named ButtonImage. Also attach ButtonDetector to that Button. You no longer need  your 

`public GameObject Button;
public GameObject Target;` variables.

Comment: Yeah for some reason just removing those variables fixed it haha. It is working beautifully thank you! But it has come with one more problem and i can't see why, it's interfering with my main mechanic, which what i've done is the further you click away from the button it changes the level of volume. Ill put the script above if you want to see it.

Comment: Hi, it would make sense to create a new post about the sound problem. This answer is made to fix your logic error in your original question. Providing more answers will make this unnecessary long. I suggest you create a new question, include your new code and then describe your problem

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to accept answer if your Button click problem in your question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest fix for you would be to make sure your loseObject script executes after your first script. You can do that with the script execution order. If you go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Script Execution Order you can add your loseObject script and draw it below "Default". Then your other script will execute first and set the amount to 0 as you would expect. However, after it gets set to 0, loseObject will still increment by one, so what you actually want to do is set amount to -1.

Comment: Hi Zite, thanks for your response. Unfortunately, the problem still persists. As soon as i saw your comment i thought that should definitely fix it but it hasn't.